# Does MAGMI work with Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, magmi

Does anyone have any experience with MAGMI and Magento 1.8? Either the .7.x branch or the .8beta branch?

Comment: Still looking for more/official feedback... but I successfully made a handful of simple attribute changes using .7.18 set to "1.7.x"...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about official Magmi compatibly and not the Magento platform

Comment: This is on topic to my eyes.  Magmi is a terrifically common open-source companion product for Magento.  Now, an answer would be nice.

Comment: Sy Moen, I have imported around 26000 configurable+simple product using magmi on magento 1.8.1 and it works fine. I got all the products and it's images

Comment: @Ram Sharma what is the version of magmi you used?

Comment: well, I am using MAGMI 0.7.18. I have break my csv into 2 parts, one for simple products and other for configurable products and imported simple products first than configurable products. It's working fine in my case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about compatibility of a 3rd party module. The OP should contact the vendor directly.

Comment: I did not have any experiance but AvS_FastSimpleImport works great in 1.7 and 1.8 https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/

Comment: Perhaps you can check over at https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git